# Displaying Sum of Objects from Django Model into Template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am using Django 1.8.3 and Python 3.4.3

I have a model which returns a list of objects to my template with a 'for' loop; one of the tables is for 'sales'. I would like to create a tag that is the Sum of off all 'sales' and insert the total_sales into my template with a tag.  The premise is to keep from having to manually add all the columns together to get the total and just have a section on the page that automatically calculates and displays the total.

Below is my current model/view.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

model.py

```
class Traffic(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    traffic = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    day_of_week = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    ifs_signups = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    campaigns = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    sales = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)

    def month(self):
        return self.date.strftime("%B")

    def quarter(self):
        item = self.date.strftime("%B")
        q1 = (["January", "February", "March"])
        q2 = (["April", "May", "June"])
        q3 = (["July", "August", "September"])
        q4 = (["October", "November", "December"])

        if item in q1:
            return "1st Quarter"
        elif item in q2:
            return "2nd Quarter"
        elif item in q3:
            return "3rd Quarter"
        elif item in q4:
            return "4th Quarter"
        else:
            return "No Date Specified"

    def conversions(self):
        conversion = self.sales / self.traffic
        return "%r" % conversion
```

views.py (the def _total_sales(self): below i my attempt)

```
from django.db.models import Sum

from .models import Traffic, Email


class TrafficListView(ListView):
    model = Traffic
    template_name = 'dashboard/pages/traffic.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TrafficListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

    def _total_sales(self):
        return self.objects.aggregate(total_sales=Sum('sales'))
```

Comment: Well, you've defined the method, now all you have to do is call it in `get_context_data` to add it to the context, surely?

Comment: Thank you.  `context['total_sales'] = Traffic.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('sales')).get('sales__sum', 0.00)` Works now!!